# Python list to dictionary with keys

Tags: python, list

I have the following list:

```
[['Andorra', '19165'], ['Algeria', '233724']]
```

The first value in each sublist is - country

The second value in each sublist is - population

How do I create a dictionary out of this list which will set `country` key and `population` key to each value inside sub-list.

I am expecting this result:

```
{'Country': 'Andora', 'population': '19165'}, ....
```

Comment: Please show the exact output you want.

Comment: Also, please show what research you did, and what you've tried.

Comment: @PHPLover I rolled back your edit, because it made your question useless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about:

```
result = {country:pop for country,pop in source}
```

where `source` is your list of sublists.

Or in the shell:

```
>>> source = [['Andorra', '69165'], ['Algeria', '40375954'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', '92738'], ['Azerbaijan', '9868447'], ['Australia', '24309330'], ['Aruba', '104263'], ['Albania', '2903700'], ['American Samoa', '55602'], ['Afghanistan', '33369945'], ['Anguilla', '14763'], ['Austria', '8569633'], ['Armenia', '3026048'], ['Angola', '25830958'], ['Argentina', '43847277']]
>>> {country:pop for country,pop in source}
{'Andorra': '69165', 'Angola': '25830958', 'Austria': '8569633', 'Armenia': '3026048', 'Anguilla': '14763', 'American Samoa': '55602', 'Albania': '2903700', 'Australia': '24309330', 'Afghanistan': '33369945', 'Aruba': '104263', 'Azerbaijan': '9868447', 'Argentina': '43847277', 'Antigua and Barbuda': '92738', 'Algeria': '40375954'}
```

## EDIT

After rereading your question, I think you look for:

```
result = [{'country':country,'population':pop} for country,pop in source]
```

This gives:

```
>>> source = [['Andorra', '69165'], ['Algeria', '40375954'], ['Antigua and Barbuda', '92738'], ['Azerbaijan', '9868447'], ['Australia', '24309330'], ['Aruba', '104263'], ['Albania', '2903700'], ['American Samoa', '55602'], ['Afghanistan', '33369945'], ['Anguilla', '14763'], ['Austria', '8569633'], ['Armenia', '3026048'], ['Angola', '25830958'], ['Argentina', '43847277']]
>>> [{'country':country,'population':pop} for country,pop in source]
[{'population': '69165', 'country': 'Andorra'}, {'population': '40375954', 'country': 'Algeria'}, {'population': '92738', 'country': 'Antigua and Barbuda'}, {'population': '9868447', 'country': 'Azerbaijan'}, {'population': '24309330', 'country': 'Australia'}, {'population': '104263', 'country': 'Aruba'}, {'population': '2903700', 'country': 'Albania'}, {'population': '55602', 'country': 'American Samoa'}, {'population': '33369945', 'country': 'Afghanistan'}, {'population': '14763', 'country': 'Anguilla'}, {'population': '8569633', 'country': 'Austria'}, {'population': '3026048', 'country': 'Armenia'}, {'population': '25830958', 'country': 'Angola'}, {'population': '43847277', 'country': 'Argentina'}]
```

Comment: How do you know that's what OP wants? He mentioned sublist there.. I think the question is unclear.

Comment: @MarounMaroun: based on what the OP states in his question: *How do I create a dictionary out of this list which will set country key and population key to each value inside sub-list.*

Comment: This code does not set a country and population key to each value :(

Comment: @PHPLover: can you give an example of a country missing?

Comment: I needthe following result:

Comment: just use `dict(source)` (before the EDIT)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you'e looking for

```
[{'country': country, 'population': population} for country, population in l]
```

Output:

```
[{'population': '69165', 'country': 'Andorra'}, {'population': '40375954', 
  'country': 'Algeria'}, {'population': '92738', 'country': 'Antigua and Barbuda'}, 
 {'population': '9868447', 'country': 'Azerbaijan'}, {'population': '24309330', 'country': 
  'Australia'}, {'population': '104263', 'country': 'Aruba'}, {'population': '2903700', 
  'country': 'Albania'}, {'population': '55602', 'country': 'American Samoa'},
 {'population': '33369945', 'country': 'Afghanistan'}, {'population': '14763', 
  'country': 'Anguilla'}, {'population': '8569633', 'country': 'Austria'}, 
 {'population': '3026048', 'country': 'Armenia'}, {'population': '25830958', 
  'country': 'Angola'}, {'population': '43847277', 'country': 'Argentina'}]
```

Comment: Yes this probably is what the OP was looking for +1. Weird `'Aruba'` is highlighted in blue.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I had box selection enabled on my terminal for some reason, and missed a `'`